# How to set DataMapper String length to unlimited for PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, postgresql, datamapper

Granted, one could use `property :foo, Text, lazy: false` all over the place to replace `property :foo, String` but that, of course, defeats several purposes in one go. Or I could use manual migrations, which I have been doing—I'm looking around now to see if they can finally be abandoned, insofar as VARCHAR v. TEXT is concerned.

In other words, I'd like automigrate to create TEXT fields for PostgreSQL for models with String properties rather than arbitrarily, pointlessly, constrained VARCHAR atop a TEXT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a lousy but working solution I came up with—if you've better one please add it and I'll accept that instead.

In `config/initializers/postgresql_strings.rb`

```
module DataMapper
  module Migrations
    module PostgresAdapter
      def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
      end

      module ClassMethods

        def type_map
          precision = Property::Numeric.precision
          scale     = Property::Decimal.scale

          super.merge(
            Property::Binary => { :primitive => 'BYTEA' },
            BigDecimal => { :primitive => 'NUMERIC', :precision => precision, :scale => scale },
            Float => { :primitive => 'DOUBLE PRECISION' },
            String => { :primitive => 'TEXT' } # All that for this
          ).freeze
        end
      end

    end
  end
end

# If you're including dm-validations, it will surprisingly attempt
# to validate strings to <= 50 characters, this prevents that.
DataMapper::Property::String.auto_validation(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Postgres adapter](http://datamapper.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/lib/data_mapper/adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb) seems to be able to handle it:

```
# size is still required, as length in postgres behaves slightly differently
def size
  case self.type
  #strings in postgres can be unlimited length
  when :string then return (@options.has_key?(:length) || @options.has_key?(:size) ? @size : nil)
  else nil
  end
end
```

Untested suggestion, but considering the [source of initialize](http://rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/Property/String#initialize-instance_method), and the length function immediately beneath it, try passing nil as the length, or no length at all.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of a few throw-it-and-see-if-comes-back ideas I tried :) Comes back with something to the effect of length has to be Integer or Range. No length gets us the default length which is 50! It should be unlimited, and a bug to that effect was closed as resolved a long time ago, but either it didn't make it in or got lost along the way.

Comment: Alternatively, try using Sequel. That one feels much more natural if you understand SQL - and much more powerful, insofar as I've been (cursorily) testing. It even supports with-queries and trigger functions.